# tab bar items need to change image and title

Tags: iphone

I need to change my tab bar items. image and title.

Initially app have four tab bar items.... 1. home 2.search 3.favorites 4. more.

Home tab bar have tableview with navigation. when i do navigation i need to change more tab bar to bookmark tab bar......

bookmarks tab bar its replace the more tab bar.

When i complete it again show more tab bar.....

Thanks in advance.

... sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

On your UITabBarController, which is probably on or close to your root controller you can adjust what viewcontrollers its simply an array

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated